# Clair V4 installation errors

Tags: docker, clair

Can someone help me setting up clair with a docker image which is relatively same as
git@github.com:Charlie-belmer/Docker-security-example.git

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./docker-utils/postgres-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ChangeMe
            - POSTGRES_USER=clair
            - POSTGRES_DB=clair

    clair:
        image: quay.io/coreos/clair:v4.3.4
        restart: unless-stopped
        volumes:
            - ./docker-utils/clair-config/:/config/:ro
            - ./docker-utils/clair-tmp/:/tmp/:rw
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_started
        command: [-conf, /config/config.yml]
        user: root

    clairctl:
        image: jgsqware/clairctl:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            - DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.41
        volumes:
            - ./docker-utils/clairctl-reports/:/reports/:rw
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        depends_on:
            clair:
                condition: service_started
        user: root
```

error i am getting is
2022/02/25 04:20:33 failed to validate config: indexer mode requires a database connection string

It works perfectly with clair's 2.0.6 (https://github.com/Charlie-belmer/Docker-security-example/blob/master/clair/docker-compose.yml).
How exactly I should find out what is the problem ? Clair's github is useless since they do not provide me a single docker file for my CI/CD. Any help would be appreciated.